# Factor-augmenting technologies (Acemoglu and Restrepo 2018c)

Tags: macroeconomics, labor-economics, theory, technology

In that paper, they consider the following production function:

$Y = F(A_KK,A_LL)$.

Where:

> K denotes capital, L is labor, and $A_K$ and $A_L$ denote capital-augmenting
>   and labor-augmenting technology, respectively. We assume throughout
>   that F is continuously differentiable, concave, and exhibits constant
>   returns to scale. Let $F_K$ and $F_L$ denote the derivatives of F with
>   respect to capital and labor. We focus on competitive labor markets,
>   which implies that the equilibrium wages is equal to the marginal
>   product of labor:

$W = A_L F_L(A_KK,A_LL)$.

Why? Shouldn't simply be:

$W = F_L(A_KK,A_LL)$.

Without the $A_L$ multiplying the derivative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chain rule! To make it simple call $\tilde{L} = A_L L$ and $\tilde{K} = A_K K$, so that

$$
Y = F(\tilde{K}, \tilde{L})
$$

so that

$$
\frac{\partial Y}{\partial L} = \frac{\partial \tilde{L}}{\partial L}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \tilde{L}} = A_L F_L(A_K K, A_L L)
$$

the trick here is that you should read $F_L$ as the derivative of $F$ with respect to its second argument.

Comment: Thanks! I understand. But don't you think it's confusing to call $F_L$ what is actually $F_{(A_LL)}$? Is there a reason for doing so?

Comment: @Tecon Yes it is :) But labor is the result of applying $A_L$ to $L$, so in that sense the marginal product of labor is $F_{(A_L L)}$